# Excel 2010 insert a custom worksheet template that has references to a named range that exists on a worksheet that already exists in the workbook?

Tags: templates, range, excel-2010, worksheet, named

I have an Excel workbook that contains a named range, called "Office_Personnel" on the first worksheet, called ""Report Tracker." When a new inspection is accomplished, the information is entered on a new worksheet that contains drop down menus that reference "Office_Personnel." I have created a macro enabled template with the drop down menus that will be inserted for each new inspection. When the template is inserted, Excel asks to update links but then states that it cannot find Office_Personnel and then the drop down menus don't work. Since this product is created for other people to use, I can't expect people to know how to remake the drop down menus. Is there a way to create a template that will reference the workbook it is inserted into? Any suggestions would be very appreciated.